# what is the meaning of following code?

Tags: java, android

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{   
    ImageView img;
    if (convertView == null) 
    {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
        img = new ImageView(mContext);
        img.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
        img.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        img.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
    } 
    else
    {
        img = (ImageView) convertView;
    }

    img.setImageResource(mThumbId[position]);
    return img;
}
```

Comment: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html#adapterperformance

Comment: You should really look in documentation for the methods you don't understand, as this question is not specific enough.

Answer (score 4):

This appears to be the part of a `ListAdapter` or `BaseAdapter` that defines the view for a list entry. When called, `position` is the index into the list for the item being populated, `convertView` is either an old view to re-use, or null (where you must allocate it).

The returned `ImageView`, `img`, is the view that will be added to the `ListView`, `GridView`, or any other `AdapterView`.